# Enabling a diverter in fakenet-ng on Ubuntu Linux disables all network traffic

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, docker, sniffing

I am trying to capture network traffic from within a docker container running Ubuntu. I am using Flare's Fakenet-ng for this, as I didn't find any better tool suited for the job (capturing network traffic from a specific process, stopping it from reaching the internet and spoofing responses to it).

For development, I am connecting to the docker instance via VNC to test things. Unfortunatley, setting `DivertTraffic: Yes` in the config, even when turning off everything else or whitelisting only a specific port/program always cuts off the VNC connection and any other network connection as well.

Does anybody have any clue as to how to work around this? Or tips for different software to use to achieve my goal?

Comment: Docker modifies networks settings in such a way you should never use Docker to do network experiments (even if not actively used, booting with Docker enabled is enough for these changes).

Comment: My goal is to have a docker instance inside which a program runs, whose network traffic gets captured, not forwarded to the internet and spoofed responses are sent back for any request it makes. This is a requirement, and as such, I cannot do this outside docker. Do you have a suggestion on how else to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I've come to the conclusion that this is probably a bug in fakenet-ng's diverter driver. There are versions of linux where it supposedly works (mainly older ones), but it failed on all which I've tried.
As there doesn't seem to be any reasonable workaround other than writing my own diverter driver (which I don't want to do), it's best to turn toward other solutions.
A possible alternative solution is being discussed in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1758477/logging-network-traffic-of-a-specific-app-in-linux-inside-docker-stopping-it-fr).