# Logging network traffic of a specific app in Linux inside docker, stopping it from reaching the internet and spoofing responses

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, docker, sniffing

I have an app (Google's Android Emulator running via QEMU) running on Ubuntu inside a docker instance.
I want to:

- Capture all network traffic (packets) comming from a VM running inside QEMU.
- Prevent traffic from that VM from reaching the internet while leaving the rest of the instance connected
- Spoof responses to requests made from that VM to other servers, pretending that I am those servers
- Do all of this in an automated headless way (no user input, just scripts)

When researching this, I discovered https://github.com/mandiant/flare-fakenet-ng, which is exactly what I need. The issue is that it doesn't seem to work in my setup (whenever Fakenet's network driver loads, it disables all network traffic regardless of any configs and I lose control of the docker instance). I asked a question about it here ([Enabling a diverter in fakenet-ng on Ubuntu Linux disables all network traffic](https://superuser.com/q/1757121/1754821)), but received no answers.

Since I haven't managed to fix this problem so far, I'm looking for a different way to achieve this.
What tools and methods should I use? What are their upsides and downsides?

Comment: You do not specify if you want to spoof QEMU traffic, or the traffic of QEMU VMs

Comment: I want to spoof responses to traffic coming from a QEMU VM. Edited my question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Emulator itself contains an implementation of tcpdump and an option to dump packets to a file. Use it like this `emulator -tcpdump {path_to_dump}.pcap {other_options}`.

As for stopping it from reaching the internet and spoofing responses, its possible to launch the emulator in a separate user group and do iptables filtering based on GIDs of processes, redirecting all traffic coming from the specific GID to a local server, where spoofed responses would be implemented.
Something like https://pypi.org/project/spoof/ or https://pypi.org/project/fake-server/ might work for this usecase.